# Vue 2, how to data bind to an element that is "data bound"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2

I created a jsfiddle for this:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57zdxg6f/)

Basically I have a three text areas.  When you enter copy in the first, it should bind to the second, which would also flow to the third.

```
<div id="app">
<textarea v-model="first"></textarea>

<textarea v-model="second">{{first}}</textarea>
 <textarea>{{ second }}</textarea>
```

Comment: Is there a reason first, second, and third aren't all the same data model?

Comment: Yes, these are dynamic.  But maybe that would still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `watch` properties to catch any change in `first` value and assign it to the `second` and so on :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    first: '',
    second: '',
    third:''
  },
  watch:{
     first(val){
     this.second=val;
     },
        second(val){
     this.third=val;
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
<textarea v-model="first"></textarea>


<textarea v-model="second" ></textarea>
  <p>2 >> {{ second }}</p>
  <textarea v-model="third" ></textarea>
   <p>3 >> {{ third }}</p>
</div>
```